Strain energy, binding affinity, penalties in protein-ligand interactions
I am not sure I understand the concepts of penalties and the relationship between strain energy and binding affinity in protein-ligand interactions.
I was reading that strain energy can be calculated by comparing the energy of the bound conformation of a ligand with the corresponding global minima on its gas or solution phase potential energy surface, and that this is important to know because if the bound conformation is very different from the low energy conformation then the molecule is paying a price/penalty to reach that conformation.
Does it mean that a molecule will spend 0 energy to reach the lowest energy conformation but it will be paying a price (energy) to reach a non-global minimum conformation? Which equation to help me reason about all of this. Also, how does strain energy affect binding affinity (delta G)?
Thanks a lot for your help.

You are talking about biomolecules aren't you? So maybe say it... And dial down to one question.

Thanks @Mithoron. I edited the question to highlight this
